# Why are redirections not working following assignment?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, command-substitution

`./NulFile` contains NUL. When command expansion removes NUL from it, it outputs warnings. Is there some way to suppress the warnings?

Why are redirections not working?

```
$ filecontent="$(cat ./NulFile)" 1>/dev/null 2>&1
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a command group and redirect the output of the group:

```
$ foo=$(cat /bin/sleep)
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
$ { foo=$(cat /bin/sleep); } 2>/dev/null
$
```

Because `{ ...; }` isn't a subshell, the variable will still be available.

```
$ echo ${#foo}
19786
```

The warning is from the shell, and you need to redirect the shell's output for it to work. In the group, even the shell's output is redirected (only within that group).

Comment: It works. Do you know why my command didn't work?

Comment: That's the last paragraph of my answer.